# Open multiple accordions with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

i have two accordions, now my task is  if i can click any one accordion it will open(Expand) two accordions automatically and if i close any one automatically close(Collapse) two accordions.It is possible?Please any one help me with example code.I'm using bootstrap and jquery.

Comment: You have to post the problem code... Then we can help.. You cannot expect code from people here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

Fiddler: https://jsfiddle.net/99x50s2s/119/

**Solution Applied:**

- Use common class for accordion control and toggle them on the click event of the links in header

**Code:**

```
$('.collapse-link').on('click', function(){
    $('.collapseOne').collapse('toggle');
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading headingOne" role="tab">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapse-link" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-collapse collapseOne collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Some test content 1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading headingOne" role="tab">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapse-link" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-collapse collapseOne collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Some test content 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Hi ganesh i facing one problem, i have four accordions left side two(LHS1,LHS2) and right side two(RHS1,RHS2) accordions.Now i'm opened LHS1 then RHS1 also open automatically.Now i'm opened LHS2 then RHS2 open automatically in LHS2 opening time top of LHS1 is collapsed but RHS1 is not collapsed.

Comment: @NavyaPrasad, can you share your code causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this `fiddle`, This does the job but in a bit different way.

It expands and Collapses on a `anchor tag` click

http://jsfiddle.net/s5hAw/781/

You can also check this simple `plugin`, That does the job

http://accordion-cd.blogspot.in/

Comment: hi subramanyam,i don't want expand all and collapse all hyper links. I want only two accordions only if u click first accordion it will open and automatically open second one also.

Comment: hey see that , Also you can use bootstrap accordion, http://www.bootply.com/tagged/accordion

Comment: hi kisspa,i don't want open all and close all.